# Java swing requestFocusInWindow()

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, focus, jtextfield

I know there are many questions on how to focus on a certain text field and so on, but it seems that the issue I am facing is a bit different. So, I have a `JTextField` which has functionality to autocomplete the text if something that is currently in it has been typed before by the user. I also have a set of buttons that perform insertion of some predefined portion of text into the text field when pressed. The problem is that every time any new text appears in the text field, the autocomplete can trigger and append the text that was used by the user previously. In order to it more friendly, I decided to select the part appended by the autocomplete. All the code is executed in the ED thread. Consider the case when the text field was not in focus :

Both code samples are in the `actionPerformed` method of the button.

`// does not work
    if (textField.requestFocusInWindow()) {
        textField.getDocument().insertString(...);
    }`

The `insertString()` is overriden and has all the logic to select appended string by the autocomplete. So, the only thing I need is that the text field is selected before the string is inserted.

I tried :

`// does work
    textField.requestFocusInWindow();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        textField.getDocument().insertString(...);
    });`

The official doc says :

> The call to the requestFocusInWindow method initiates the focus transfer, but it does not immediately move the focus ...

This sort of makes sense, since to acquire the focus, a call must be made to the window manager of the clients operating system (that's how I understand that, correct me if I am wrong).

Is the second example working mainly because both events (getting focus and inserting the string) are added to the event queue and the insertion appears after the focus request (actually at the end of the queue) or am I missing something? Is it a valid solution? Can it be done better?

Note: simply adding a listener to the text field ( to react when it is in focus) is not a solution, since the logic I described here is only a part of the whole functionality used.

Comment: Why do you need the text field to request focus again?

Comment: Because it can be the case that it is not in focus initially and as I understand `insertString` is not doing that.

Comment: To answer the general question, `invokeLater` is allowing a certain amount of time to pass from when you call `requestFocusInWindow` till when the `Runnable` is called, which is allowing the rest of the API to respond to the OS's notification that it's gained focus - so it's kind of a race condition ... and use the term loosely. The reason I ask the question is, why do you need the field to have focus to update it? I'm wondering if setting the components to be unfocusable "might" provide a more stable solution, but you'd need to figure out how to allow keyboard interaction, which isn't hard